# Redirect all requests about an special URL to Another URL in windows by using a simple C# webserver application

Tags: c#, windows, redirect, webserver, hosts

I want redirect a special URL to another URL in windows.

I know the **`Hosts`** file in

> %windir%\System32\drivers\etc

- **Entry Site (A):**   **https**://my.example.com/home/
- **Target Site (B):**   **http**://www.another-example.com/p/sl/index

**But** my B URL has not a direct IP (the target `site B` is on a host with a shared `IP` to provide some website)

So i can't use `Hosts` file in this scenario. Yes??? Do you know a simple way?

---

**Now** i want write a `small C# web server` to listen port 80 and all request about `Site A URL` in windows (*Internet Browsers and Applications*) to redirect it to `Site B URL`.

What do you think about the solution? How can i do this simply?
I need a simple example or a simple best practice guide to do it.
Thanks

---

**EDIT:**

- I have not the source code of site A
- The site B is mine.

I want redirect Site A URL requests to Site B URL after installing and running my C# Application on client windows. My question is how can i create this application to listen right the URL A and Show the user URL B.

Comment: Putting a meta-refresh tag in an html page on your machine that redirects to another site or html page on your machine does not require a web server.  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes...  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have not the source code of site A! I have just site B. Site A is like: google, adobe or... so I have not its source code of html or ....

Comment: So, you want to hijack all requests to a specific page and redirect them to another page?

Comment: So, why not use the hosts file to redirect to a local html file that redirects to your site b?

Comment: @paqogomez, Yes i want find a simple mechanism to redirect all requests of site A URL from internet browsers or applications on the client windows to my special B URL. I think, i can do this if write a simple c# application and give it to client to run... and the application do listening and redirecting...

Comment: @paqogomez, may you give me a simple example about using a local html file and Hosts file together?! any example of a line of code in hosts file?

Comment: So you want an app that listens on port 80 and reads the http requests, then redirects if a specific match is found.  This is possible, but your question is far too broad.  You need to start coding and come back when you have an error

Comment: @paqogomez, exactly... but i want some suggested Links (simple good example) to start in this way... do you think i can solve it just by Hosts file yet?! My question generally because i want simplest way. maybe you say to me: Sure! You can do this by Hosts file, so i don't write the C# application! I'm finding the simplest way...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76370/discussion-between-ram-and-paqogomez).